# pysolr python can no decode json

Tags: python, json, solr, pysolr

I got a pysolr instance and I try to get this simple query.
I use python 2.7 and pysolr 3.3.2:

When I get this query:

`solrDoc.search('platformID:RO', **{'rows': 0, 'start':5, 'sort':'id DESC'})`

I have this Json exception:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 633, in search
result = self.decoder.decode(response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

I can understand how to handle this, because my solr instance is running and I have already query solr with this Python API.
I have just updated from solr4 to solr5 but it seems that is not the point.

Answer (score 0):

No, it was not a json problem. It was a connection problem. My adress path lead nowwhere but when I create a pysolr instance (with the wrong adress path) I get no error. But when I query, I get in fact no response... indeed a no response can no be json decoded.
It is for sure a  mismanagement on exception handlers in pysolr.